# Delete Duplicate Rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in an Excel spreadsheet with several hundred entries, and some of these entries are duplicated.

I would like to remove all duplicate entries from the column so that each entry remaining is unique.

Is there a way to accomplish this automatically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not useful at all and shows up very high in searches.

Comment: @fixer1234 closing as duplicate would redirect users that see it to a useful answer (rather than links only), though I didn't link a possible duplicate.

Comment: @fixer1234 I've nominated it for reopening. We might want to redirect the others back to this one if it gets reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Remove Duplicates feature of Excel.

1. Select your data.
2. Click `Remove Duplicates` on the Data ribbon.
3. Choose which columns to use as criteria for duplicate entries. In your case, it's one column, so just select the single column.

   [image]
4. Click `OK`.

   [image]